# Wordpress Get posts by post id in exact order as in array

Tags: wordpress

How can I get posts by post id in same order as in array?

I tried:

```
<?php

$ids = array(548,555,587,583,585);

$my_query = query_posts(array('post__in' => $ids));

global $post;

foreach ($my_query as $post){
$posts_by_id[$post->ID] = $post;
}

foreach ($ids as $id)  {

if (!$post = $posts_by_id[$id]) continue;
setup_postdata($post);
//do something
echo '<p>TITLE: ';the_title();echo ' - ';the_ID(); '</p>';
the_content();

}

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all - you should probably be using WP_Query for this (unless you have a very specific use case).

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

To order your posts you can use:

`array('post__in' => $ids, 'orderby' => 'post__in'))`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Note: This is only since WP 3.5